# Flash AS3 4 If statements

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, if-statement

I would like to use 4 if statements in one line of code, because I need this many statements to account for the 4 correct responses in a multiple response quiz question.

```
if (btnChecked1C.visible == true && btnChecked2C.visible == true && btnChecked3C.visible == true && btnChecked4C.visible == true)
    scoreOut.text = "Correct";
if (btnChecked1F.visible == true && btnChecked2F.visible == true && btnChecked3F.visible == true)
    scoreOut.text = "False";
```

This code doesn't seem to work so just wondered if anyone could let me know how to get this many statements to work, or if there's a more efficient way to mark the question?

Comment: Are you sure you need `&&` and not `||` ?

Comment: "This code doesn't seem to work" doesn't help anyone. What is your expected outcome? What is the behavior you are trying to achieve? Be more clear with your question.

Comment: Beginners should not use shortcuts code writings. Put some brackets around your statements. There's nothing wrong about your code besides that except the double conditional: "if(btnChecked1C.visible == true)". This is an evaluation which will then be evaluated to true or false while you could skip directly to the evaluation with: if(btnChecked1C.visible)

Comment: Wrap equality check statement into more brackets. `if ((btnChecked1C.visible == true) && (btnChecked2C.visible == true) && ...`

Answer (score 0):

Use as many statements as you want, however I found when I had similar problems to set dynamic switches using variables or even case.

eg.

```
switch( event.something )
        {
            case Something=true:
                some code here;
                break;

            case Something=true:
                some code here;
                break;

            case Something=true:
                some code here;
                break;
        }
```

to help further I would need know how you are triggering the transparencys?  i'm assuming its through a function so I would create a function that sets a unified variable for C set. eg.

```
var Correct_C_Answers:int;

function Funtions1C (e:Event=null):void
{
    btnChecked1C.visible = true;
    Correct_C_Answers = Correct_C_Answers+1;

}

function Funtions2C (e:Event=null):void
{
    btnChecked2C.visible = true;
    Correct_C_Answers = Correct_C_Answers+1;

}

function Funtions3C (e:Event=null):void
{
    btnChecked3C.visible = true;
    Correct_C_Answers = Correct_C_Answers+1;

}

function Funtions4C (e:Event=null):void
{
    btnChecked4C.visible = true;
    Correct_C_Answers = Correct_C_Answers+1;

}

if (Correct_C_Answers == 4)
{
    scoreOut.text = "Correct";
}

if (Correct_C_Answers < 4)
{
    scoreOut.text = "False";
}
```

again its hard to help you exactly unless i know how your app functions run?  you say its a quiz, how do you / what functions do you use to check answers individually? how does user select answer Via a mouse function? or do they type answer?  If you can elaborate a bit more im sure i can help.